# TypeScript Index Signature – map keys

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to map **keys** in Index Signature type to create another type?

I can easily create an index signature type based on another index signature type:

```
type X = {a: number, b: number}

type Y = {[k in keyof X]: X[k]}
```

I can even modify type of **fields** on the fly:

```
type Y = {[k in keyof X]: string} // fields are string instead of number
```

**But is it possible to modify keys?**

Conceptually, I'd like this to work in the following manner:

```
type XYZ = {['a'+k in keyof X]: X[k]} // obviously this syntax doesn't exist
// could results in
type XYZ = {aa: number, ab: number}
```

Comment: as far as I know that is not yet possible.

Comment: @toskv do you know if there's any discussion about it? I can't find it on GitHub.

Comment: The only thing I could find that's close to is this closed thread.. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11997 and maybe this one https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579 but they are not specifically about this either..

Comment: Ryan Cavanaugh is active here too, maybe you're lucky and he sees your post. :D

Comment: Thanks @toskv :)